# Move from Standalone install to web only MOSS 2007

Tags: 2007, installation

I am trying to convert our MOSS 2007 installation from standalone to web only so that I can move our content databases from the Windows internal database to SQL Server 2008 R2. I see a [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36866/move-from-standalone-installation-to-a-small-farm-sharepoint-server-2010?newreg=64a296909f944d8ca2300e6a8afbd046) similar to what I want, except that one is for SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of what you see in that answer generally applies to 2007, as well. You'll build a new farm, restore the SSP (if applicable), restore any settings in Central Admin, create your Web App(s), restore the content databases.

Comment: Normally id wait for other answers, but really this is what i needed to know.